# Any reason C#'s List<T> Class, not having save or update method?

Tags: c#, generics, collections

C#'s `List<T>` class [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0#methods) doesn't have a `Save()` or `Update()` method. Is there any technical reason behind this?

What @MarcGravell & @Charles mentioned in Answer/Comment section, is something I'm trying to do.

If the question is clear to @MarcGravell & @Charles, I'm wondering what makes individuals like @Llama to make pretty easy statement "Question does not make sense"? Is this some kind trick to close the ticket & reduce one's workload?

To be even more specific, how to update & save the changes to specific item in the collection?

Comment: Question does not make sense. What would `Save()` mean here? What would `Update()` mean here?

Comment: It doesn't have a `Rhubarb` method either. Explain why the ones you've mentioned would *make sense*.

Comment: What are you trying to do, `myList[indexNonExist] = 10` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by `Save()` or `Update()` you mean some kind of database backend, perhaps persisting the changes, then:

1. A list has no concept of a database
2. Most lists aren't involved in anything related to a database
3. Adding the tracking necessary would significantly increase the memory required, and decrease the performance
4. For a feature that *isn't required* basically all of the time
5. And which would require vastly different logic for different kinds of backend storage, which the list can't know about

If you want this kind of feature: use an ORM such as EF, LLBLGenPro, or anything else. That's what they provide. A list is basically a fancy veneer over an oversized array, *and nothing else*, which is fine: because most of the time, that's what you want.

Comment: You should add the hint to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle

Comment: But you already did, so - meh

Comment: Yes, but I would remove my comment, when you add it

Comment: @MarcGravell, point#3 answers my question to an extent. Possibly the reason why 'list' not supporting update/save is to AVOID developers from using the 'list' for manipulation of DB entities?

Comment: @ZackieKhan not really; it just isn't a target of that type; it doesn't need to actively discourage things that have nothing to do with it